Pinning issues for struct implementing Stream
I'm trying to wrap a fastwebsockets::FragmentCollector in a struct that implements Stream<Item = Vec<u8>>. Currently, this is what I have.
struct MessageStream {
    inner: FragmentCollector<TokioIo<Upgraded>>,
    fut: Option<BoxFuture<'static, Result<Vec<u8>, Whatever>>>,
}

Now for the impl Stream, I have poll_next check if there is currently a future in self.fut, and if so, poll it for the next message. Otherwise, kick off a new future waiting for the next message and store it in self.fut.
fn poll_next(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Option<Result<Vec<u8>, Whatever>>> {
    match self.fut {
        Some(fut) => match fut.poll(cx) { // Error: Pin<Box<dyn Future<...>>> doesn't implement Future because the future isn't Unpin
            Poll::Pending => {
                self.fut.replace(fut);
                Poll::Pending
            }
            Poll::Ready(Err(e)) => Poll::Ready(Some(Err(e))),
            Poll::Ready(Ok(data)) => Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(data)))
        }
        None => {
            self.fut = Some(Box::pin(self.read_next()));
            self.poll_next(cx)
        }
    }
}

Now the kicker from a pinning perspective is that self.read_next() references self.inner and so now self.fut has captured a reference to self.inner, which makes the future !Unpin if I understand pinning correctly (big if).
async fn read_next(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Whatever> {
    loop {
        match self.inner.read_frame().await {
            Err(e) => whatever!("failed to read websocket frame: {}", e),
            Ok(frame) => match frame.opcode {
                OpCode::Close => whatever!("websocket closed"),
                OpCode::Text | OpCode::Binary => match frame.payload {
                    fastwebsockets::Payload::Owned(data) => return Ok(data),
                    _ => unreachable!(), // Depends on implementation detail of FragmentCollector, but I'm ok with that.
                },
                _ => trace!("ignoring frame with opcode {:?}", frame.opcode),
            },
        }
    }
}

What is the right way to implement this kind of wrapper? (Is there some helper macro/struct already in tokio somewhere?) Is the solution to move inner into self.fut on each call, and then return it back out, instead of holding a reference to it in self? Or do I just have to do some pinning black magic with pin! in poll_next()?
I'm new to writing this kind of low-level async rust code, and would appreciate any comments on style and approach.
